# Android SimpleXML ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, simple-framework, class-attribute

I have XML response and trying to parse it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<found>

<objects>

    <object handle="Collection-10" class="Folder" classType="Folder">
        <title>Initial Top Level Collection A</title>
    </object>

    <object handle="Collection-11" class="Folder" classType="Folder">
        <title>Initial Top Level Collection B</title>
    </object>

</objects>  

</found>
```

How can I add **package** before class name?

```
class="package.Folder"
```

Now I just use:

```
String.replaceAll(classAttributeName, classAttributeName + packageName);
```

Comment: have you coded anything ?